# Hit a curb - scraped rim and took out chunk of tire, should I replace tire?

Tags: tires, wheels

[image][![Hello, I was driving out this narrow drive thru and hit the curb as I turned to leave. It scraped my rim and took a chunk of the tire. Is it drive-able? Should I get the tire replaced? Thank you